# Mobile Phone innerWidth,innerHeight vs Resolution

Tags: javascript, android, css

One of my test phones is a Galaxy S3 Mini. The specs of this phone say it is a 800x480 resolution.

However, when I do the following in my HTML game:

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

It gives 533 for the width and 295 for the height.

Now I've read about window.devicePixelRatio, and for my phone it is 1.5
But how can this help me make my design look good?

The problem is that my game is designed for 800x480, and it looks stretched because of this.

Answer (score 0):

use this, to get Width & Height:

```
WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
d.getWidth() and d.getHeight()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `window.inner..` properties refer to the browser, not to the resolution of the screen. They are usually smaller, due to status bars, address bar and other toolbars, window borders and so on.